Why can't other bosons fluctuate up the potential curve and gain mass?
If a Higgs boson is able to gain mass by fluctuating up the Mexican hat potential, what stops other bosons from doing the same thing and gaining mass without the need of the Higgs mechanism?

Getting mass from the Mexican hat is the Higgs mechanism.
